# Does the value of a static int change in this case

Tags: c++

I currently have a header file that is included by multiple header and source files. The header file looks something like this

```
File:External.h
#ifndef EXTERNAL_H
#define EXTERNAL_H

#include "memory"

static int pid=-1;

#endif // EXTERNAL_H
```

This is a simplification of my current scenario just to check if I might be wrong.Now suppose I have two classes `foo` and `bar`. Here is the behaviour that I have noticed.

```
#include "External.h"
void foo::someMethod()
{
   pid =13; //Change the value of pid;
   bar_ptr = new bar();
}

//bar constrcutor
#include "External.h"
bar::bar()
{
   int a = pid;  //The value of a is -1 wasnt it suppose to be 13
}
```

Wasnt the value of a suppose to be 13 especially since its an open variable (not a struct or class) of static type.?

Comment: The `static` specifier gives the name `pid` internal linkage, so it refers to a distinct entity in each translation unit.

Comment: Please post real code. We can probably make a fairly reliable guess at the answer, but your question should still reproduce the problem. As it is, you've cut a few corners that I can spot right away.

Comment: hmm.. ok thanks for clearing that up. This was confusing me

Comment: You have two distinct pid variables here .. or more precisely one in every file which includes that header.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet I understand that. I tried to replicate my situation as I was unable to post a whole project. I will however attempt to clear this up if anyone has questions.

Comment: You shouldn't post a whole project either but the [minimal, complete testcase](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with which you've been debugging the problem so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because each file is including the header, and thus each compilation unit (roughly source file) will have this definition inside of it:

```
static int pid=-1;
```

Thus they each have their own copy.

Really you should do something like:

> External.h

```
// The declaration, so that people can access it
extern int pid;
```

> External.c

```
// The actual implementation
int pid = -1;
```

Comment: can it be External.cpp ?

Comment: Yes, you can call it External.cpp